# Packages not found error package not available from current channel python3.7

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm getting Packages not found error; how do I find channel I need?

This is what i got

```
PS C:\Users\username> conda config --append channels conda-forge
(base) PS C:\Users\username> conda create -n voice-clone python3.7
WARNING: A directory already exists at the target location 'C:\Users\phitc\anaconda3\envs\voice-clone'
but it is not a conda environment.
Continue creating environment (y/[n])? y

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python3.7

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I ran this yesterday no problems, I'm sure this is easy, just started with python/anaconda yesterday... any help is most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the package should be `python=3.7`, not `python3.7`, as you're looking for a specific *version*, not that name!

Comment: Thanks to both answers, I installed specific package, then ran again, got same error, retyped command with  the python=3.7, instead of python3.7, and it worked, strange that it ran yesterday with the python3.7 syntax, and ran today with the python=3.7 syntax//...if anyone knows why , please leave comment

Comment: Any time! If this solved your Question, please mark it as the Answer with the check to its left to help everyone on the platform!